# jquery find button in row and change its class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table and buttons and all buttons are getting generated with a loop.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-connetion" name="button">
<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</button>
```

I want to find which button I click and then change its class.

now in my jquery script

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.remove-connetion', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 $('td').find('.fa fa-trash').closest('button').removeClass('btn-danger');
 $('td').find('.fa fa-trash').closest('button').addClass('btn-secondary');

});
```

it's not changing class.
Thanks for all help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this` instead inside the callback to get the current clicked button:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.remove-connetion', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var clicked = $(this);
  setTimeout( function() {
     clicked.removeClass('btn-danger');
     clicked.addClass('btn-secondary');
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-connetion" name="button">
   <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-connetion" name="button">
   <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-connetion" name="button">
   <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Or just `$(this).toggleClass('btn-danger btn-secondary');`

Comment: one more thing but this is not working when I use it under ajax like $.ajax({ and after success: function(result){

Comment: You can save the element in that scope to use it later, check my updated code by simulating the ajax call with the setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
$( document ).on( 'click', '.remove-connetion', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.remove('btn-danger');
  e.target.classList.add('btn-secondary');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-connetion" name="button">
<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Waste of jQuery to go after the e.target

Comment: @mplungjan I agree, just thought I'd add an alternate solution... the `this` method was already posted